# Mojave doesn't remember window position/size for a specific application?

Tags: terminal, automator

Normally on Mojave all applications windows settings are stored automatically.
Still I have one program which does not do this, every time I re-open this app I have to maximize (not full screen) it's window all over again.

Is there any way I can achieve this automatically?
Making that the program will remember windows size and position after closing an reopening?
Maybe a plist file, terminal command, automator, or third party application which does this automatically?

Many THANKS for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the list of solutions:

Open a **Finder** window, hold down the <kbd>option</kbd> key and resize the window as you wish. Close all Finder windows and next time you open a new one it will remember the size.

Meanwhile, you can use an app like [Stay](https://cordlessdog.com/stay/) to remember and automatically reset the position of any window.

You might also look at window managers such as [Magnet](https://magnet.crowdcafe.com/) that allow easy manipulation of windows.

Comment: Magnet has no relation to what is asked.